# Access value of a cell in a range that makes an if statement true in excel

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, range

I want check if a cell is equal to a cell in a range of others. And if it is I want to add the value of a cell in a different column to the total.

So lets say I'm searching the range A2:A1000 to see if it is equal to B2 (IF(A2:A1000=B2,1,0))
Lets say B2 is equal to A5.  I then want to add C5 to my sum in D2.

Is this possible in excel?

Comment: `SUMIF()` should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim A As Range, B2 As Range, C5 As Range, D2 As Range
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long
    Set A = Range("A2:A1000")
    Set B2 = Range("B2")
    Set C5 = Range("C5")
    Set D2 = Range("D2")
    v = B2.Value
    For i = 2 To 1000
        If v = Cells(i, "A").Value Then
            D2.Value = D2.Value + C5.Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```